# How to parse string into byte[]

Tags: c#, string, parsing, arrays

I have a string in c# which contains the following..

```
SMDR#0D#0APCCSMDR#0D#0A
```

Now as per my requirement i need to parse this into byte[] with the same formate..I have to show the byte[] as

```
SMDR#0D#0APCCSMDR#0D#0A
```

This i am needed because the my function takes arguments in this formate of byte[] and the value that i need to pass is this only..

```
SMDR#0D#0APCCSMDR#0D#0A
```

How to achieve this.Do i need to change in the string formate or byte[]..

Comment: Can you make an effort and put a bit of context in your question? How does this function need to manipulate the byte[]? What text enconding does it need to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really confused with your question, but if you need your string represented as `byte[]` you can use LINQ:

```
var output = input.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
```

Comment: This will silently discard the data if the char is not in the ASCII range.  If that is desired, then sure.  But why not just use `Encoding.ASCII` or `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using following code, I hope this will answer your question.

FROM http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-byte-array

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Text;
>
> class Program
> {
>     static void Main()
>     {
>   // Input string.
>   const string input = "Dot Net Perls";
>
>   // Invoke GetBytes method.
>   // ... You can store this array as a field!
>   byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
>
>   // Loop through contents of the array.
>   foreach (byte element in array)
>   {
>       Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", element, (char)element);
>   }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions

Comment: What assumptions? I would write the same thing, rather than a string=>linq=>array that silently discards data.  The assumption is now right there... Encoding.Ascii.  Change that if you need.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is hopefully a more explanatory answer...

Getting the bytes doesn't technically depend on the encoding, since it is just memory.  However, interpreting the sequence of bytes does.  What encoding does the function you are calling expect?

If it is expecting raw ascii bytes:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello, 你是天才"); // 11 bytes. chinese truncated
```

If it is expecting the UTF-8 data (1 byte ascii, 2-4 bytes for others):

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello, 你是天才"); // 19 bytes, as utf8
```

If it wants a double width characters (2 bytes each, UCS-2):

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("hello, 你是天才") // 22 bytes
```

And so on and on.  Check out the `System.Text.Encoding` class for more details and options.

Answer (score 0):

**just try this code**

```
string str="SMDR#0D#0APCCSMDR#0D#0A";
byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 foreach (var item in bytes)
        {
            Response.Write((char)item);
        }
```

for more clarify read from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How to take the output of this line System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length); into byte[] array

Comment: @Adi BlockCopy copy all char of a string parameter, to byte array.